# Controls(textbox, label etc.,) are not display in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

We are performing navigation from one viewcontroller(Login) to another viewcontroller(Home).In HomeViewController we are generating the buttons dynamically, and also need some static controls(label,textbox etc.,), but static controls are not display in simulator.[image]

this "welcome" and "select route:" labels are not showing in simulator, simulator showing only dynamic buttons as follows:[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does size class and autolayout enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with autolayout if you are using it but not constraining your static content.

[image]

check if use Auto Layout is checked in your interface builder document. (first tab in the left utilities menu). If so, you should add constraints to your static content so that it is located where you want it to be on whatever devices/orientations.

Comment: I have Added the constrainsts to my label i.e,welcome but also the label wasnot displaying ,not only label any other  static fields are not displaying but if i generate through code for any label or textbox i was displaying.hope i will get an answer to my Question.Thanks in Advance